# CalendarView not working properly

Tags: java, android

I wrote a program for a calendarview which is not working properly as i want.
Firstly i have a button which when clicked opens up a new activity which has a linear layout inside that i have 3 textviews for day month year , i have a dialog box opening up on the click of linear layout , as i said i have 3 textviews inside my linear layout and instead of using three different click listeners , i used the onclick with the help of linear layout id , so my calendar dialog is opening up , but when i m using calendar.setOnDateChangeListener my app crashes giving me an error on this listener , now i want to know where i should use the setondatechangelistener , inside my activity class ?? or inside my fragment class ??
because my calendar dialog is opening up on the click ,  but i want to set the dates inside my textview when i select a particular date
need some help please

Below here is my code for the above explanation and i have also commented my calender.setondatechangelistener

My MainActivity.java

```
l1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            CalendarAlert dialog = new CalendarAlert();

            dialog.show(manager, "MyDialog");

        }

    });

    /*

      calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

      @Override public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int
      year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      } });
     */

}
```

My CalenderAlert.java

```
public class CalendarAlert extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar, container, false);
    setCancelable(true);
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java we can have class inside another class.

So put your CalendarAlert-DialogFragment  inside your activity. Make your 3 TextView globle within the class and set them inside setondatechangelistener method.